# Make TextCtrl Scale with Window

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, python-module

I've just gotten into wxpython for Python 3.6 and I've hit a roadblock. I just can't work out how to make elements/widgets scale with the screen! I know you have to use sizers but that's about it, I'm still fairly new to programming so just reading the documentation didn't help. If someone could just sample some code that works I'd be very thankful as I could then read through it and work out what I was doing wrong. The code that draws out the GUI I want to scale with window size is below, the key idea is that the TextCtrl scales, other elements don't really need scaling.

```
def createGUI(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        
        menuButton = wx.Menu()
        newItem = wx.MenuItem(menuButton, wx.ID_NEW, 'New Note\tCtrl+N')
        delItem = wx.MenuItem(menuButton, wx.ID_DELETE, 'Delete Note\tCtrl+Backspace')
        saveItem = wx.MenuItem(menuButton, wx.ID_SAVE, 'Save\tCtrl+S')
        exitItem = wx.MenuItem(menuButton, wx.ID_EXIT, 'Quit\tCtrl+Q')
        
        
        menuButton.Append(newItem)
        menuButton.Append(saveItem)
        menuButton.Append(delItem)
        menuButton.Append(exitItem)

        
        menuBar.Append(menuButton, 'Menu')
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.new, newItem)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.delete, delItem)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.save, saveItem)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onExit, exitItem)
        
        self.noteText = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        self.noteText.AppendText(self.notecontent)
        
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.onExit)
        self.SetTitle(f'Welcome {self.username}! You are working on {self.notepath}')
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)
```

Comment: Post what you've done so far, so the answer can be tailored to your requirements and any mistakes you've made, can be explained.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I've added the code in question, hope it helps.

Comment: The key issue in that code, is despite not using sizers, you don't have to, you can size and position the widgets as you see fit, you haven't declared any sizes or positions. The result is that any widgets thrown in are default sizes and default positions. If you had more than one item in there, they would all be on top of each other, for lack of positioning instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with it's best to equate sizers to something familiar and I usually think of storage boxes or a chest of drawers.
When we define widgets, they are all dumped into a container, the `parent` object, often the ubiquitous `self` or `self.panel`.
If we do not assign a `size` and `pos` to each item, it's just a jumbled mess, a pile of widgets.
The `sizer`, there are many types, are the virtual drawers in our chest of drawers, that herds this pile of widgets into order.
The widgets are assigned to the appropriate `sizer`, note sizers can go into other sizers, and eventually when everything has been assigned a place or `drawer` in our chest of drawers, the sizers do their magic, arranging and sizing all of widgets into a coherent screen for display or arranging the drawers contents and relative positions in the chest of drawers.
Below, I've used the simplest `sizer` a boxsizer.
One will arrange things vertically and the other horizontally.
The horizontal sizer is for the buttons and the vertical sizer, will be the main sizer, into which I place not only the `TectCtrl` but also the buttons, prearranged in their horizontal sizer.
For a better and more comprehensive description of sizers and their controls see: https://docs.wxpython.org/sizers_overview.html and for details on the actual sizers available see the detailed documenation on each.

A loose approximation of your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import wx
class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title,
            size=(450, 350))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.button_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.noteText = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.Button_close = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, label="Quit")
        self.Button_1 = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, label="Btn1")
        self.Button_2 = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, label="Btn2")

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.onExit)
        self.Button_close.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onExit)
        self.Button_1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)
        self.Button_2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)


        # Place buttons within their own horizontal sizer
        self.button_sizer.Add(self.Button_close,proportion=0, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        self.button_sizer.Add(self.Button_1,proportion=0, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        self.button_sizer.Add(self.Button_2,proportion=0, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)

        # Add textctrl and the button sizer to the main sizer (vertical)
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.noteText,proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=10)
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.button_sizer, 0, 0, 0)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.main_sizer)
        self.Show()

    def onExit(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

    def onButton(self, event):
        print("A button was pressed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Example(None, title="Example")
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Edit:
Here's the same code without using sizers, although they are recommended.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import wx
class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title,
            size=(450, 350))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        self.noteText = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, pos=(10,10), size=(400,280), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.Button_close = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, label="Quit", pos=(10,290), size=(50,30))
        self.Button_1 = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, label="Btn1", pos=(70,290), size=(50,30))
        self.Button_2 = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, label="Btn2", pos=(130,290), size=(50,30))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.onExit)
        self.Button_close.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onExit)
        self.Button_1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)
        self.Button_2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)
        self.Show()

    def onExit(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

    def onButton(self, event):
        print("A button was pressed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Example(None, title="Example")
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Perfect, I'm still rather clueless on how this all works but I managed to implement what I needed. Thanks again.

Comment: @NucleaTNT Remember, if `sizers` are a bit much for you at the moment, you can give each widget a `size` and a `pos` (position). In other words, you specify its size and position on the panel/frame. This has its drawbacks but allows you to crack on with the actual coding, providing a working GUI, which you can modify later when you have time to get your head around sizers.

Comment: @NucleaTNT See my edit for a non-sizer version of the code. However that flies in the face, sort of, of your original query about scaling. Without sizers, it won't scale because it will have a fixed size. You would have to recalculate its size, which is what sizers do for you automatically, which is why they're `very` popular.

Comment: gotcha, I've ended up using size and positions in my 'Are you sure you want to exit?' window instead. I'll just have to keep reading docs and examples until it clicks on how sizers work. Thanks again :D